# Turning list to gallery view when screen is rotated?

Tags: android, eclipse, listview, screen-rotation, galleryview

Currently i have a simple listview of movies and want to turn that listview into a gallery of movie pictures when rotated.  So basically i want to know if this is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a separate layout for landscape orientation, in this specific layout you can use galleryview

Comment: Thanks for quick response i will try that and see if i can get it working thankyou

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible take look at the developper documentation [Implementing adaptive UI Flow](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/adaptui.html)

You can also look at [building a flexible UI](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html)

Comment: Thank for a quick response i will look into that just now and see what i can do